# How to display a fixed amount of items in HStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to loop through an array of items and display 3 of them in one `HStack` for every other item in the array I want to display them in the next line again for 3 items and so on.

It should look something like this:
[image]

My code so far lets the items appear in the same line:

```
struct FeedBlockView: View {
    let cardSize = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3) - 1
    @State var feedPosts: [FeedPost]

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 2) {
            ForEach(feedPosts, id: \.id) { feedPost in
                WebImage(url: URL(string: feedPost.feedImageUrl))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: cardSize, height: cardSize)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

You can either use a `LazyVGrid` and have three columns:

```
import SwiftUI

LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())], spacing: 5) {
    ForEach(feedpostArray, id: \.id) { post in
        // yourCOntent
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want your views to load lazily, you can split your array so your array contains arrays that has three posts each (except the last one if the math doesn't go up):

```
VStack {
    ForEach(feedposts.chunked(into: 3), id: \.self) { feedpostArray in
        HStack(spacing: 7) {
            ForEach(feedpostArray, id: \.id) { post in
                // yourCOntent

                if feedpostArray.count != 3 {
                     // something to fill the last row it is less than three (Color.clear for example)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the extension for split:

```
// MARK: - Array to chunks
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using LazyVGrid works perfect but I had to use GridItem(.flexible()). It does work in the simulator but does not show in the preview is the a reason why that is?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain. If you have an environmentObject you also need to add that to the preview. Other than that I can't tell without seeing the code.